# What happens when you pass a sinusoidal input in an integrator circuit without opamp

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electrical-engineering

[image]When a square waves is passed into such a circuit it becomes a triangular wave , but why does the integrator circuit give the same output voltage graph when I pass a sinusoidal wave. Assuming time period is much smaller compared to the time constant of the circuit. If I pass a sine wave must not I get a cosine wave , why do I still get a sine wave

Comment: I'm not sure if this is on topic here; integrator circuits may be beyond our scope. If the community judges it not to be on topic here, we can try sending it to [electronics.SE].

Comment: What is the difference between a sine wave and a cosine wave, in your opinion?  What are you looking for to distinguish the two?

Comment: I hope the picture makes it better now....

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments this may fit better in EE SE, nevertheless here is my answer:

Intuitively,a simple RC integrator circuit (without an Op-amp) works as long as you make sure that the voltage across the capacitor is small in amplitude relative to the input amplitude. In other words - as long as the capacitor can't keep up with the changes of the voltage the circuit works well. In order to make the capacitor unable to keep up we need to make sure that the RC constant of the circuit is large compared with the period of the input signal. If this condition is not maintained the circuit won't function as requested. It may be that the input signal violates this requirement, then the capacitor just follows the input signal (because when RC is small compared with the period the capacitor follows the input with little to no phase shift).

Also, how are you sure that the output of your circuit is a sine and not a cosine? make sure you compare the output of you circuit relative to the input, if you just measure them separately and watch them on your oscilloscope screen than the waveform will look the same because of how the triggering of the oscilloscope sweep works. You need to look at both input and output at the same time and than look for the phase shift.

Answer (score 0):

Without the specific passive circuit and signal source specifications, this question is difficult to answer.

But generally speaking, without using an operational amplifier to realize your integrator, your passive circuit may not have a high input impedance relative to the signal source output impedance, and so the integrator circuit may be loading down your signal source and changing the effective, expected RC time constant.